Creating a dynamic numpy array using two existing arrays
I'm looking to multiply out two arrays (not their values). In this instance, I have an array of sequential dates which can vary and another array of values 0 to 23 (i.e. hours)
 a = np.arange(np.datetime64('2024-01-01'), np.datetime64('2024-01-11'))
and
 b = np.linspace(0, 23, 24)
How to I mutiply these into a new array such that (in the instance above) it will yield an array of 240 rows each 24 rows is a given date and sequential hours 0 to 23?
This would give an output as follows:
array([['2024-01-01', 0],['2024-01-01', 1] ... ['2024-01-10', 22],['2024-01-10', 23]])

IIUC, convert b to an array of timedelta64, then broadcast the addition and flatten with ravel:
out = (a[:, None] + b*np.timedelta64(1, 'h')).ravel()

Or:
out = np.add.outer(a, b*np.timedelta64(1, 'h')).ravel()

Output:
array(['2024-01-01T00', '2024-01-01T01', '2024-01-01T02', '2024-01-01T03',
       '2024-01-01T04', '2024-01-01T05', '2024-01-01T06', '2024-01-01T07',
       '2024-01-01T08', '2024-01-01T09', '2024-01-01T10', '2024-01-01T11',
       ...,
       '2024-01-10T20', '2024-01-10T21', '2024-01-10T22', '2024-01-10T23'],
      dtype='datetime64[h]')

If you want to columns with pairs of date/hours:
out = np.c_[np.repeat(a, len(b)).astype(object), np.tile(b, len(a))]

array([[datetime.date(2024, 1, 1), 0.0],
       [datetime.date(2024, 1, 1), 1.0],
       [datetime.date(2024, 1, 1), 2.0],
       [datetime.date(2024, 1, 1), 3.0],
       ...,
       [datetime.date(2024, 1, 1), 22.0],
       [datetime.date(2024, 1, 1), 23.0],
       [datetime.date(2024, 1, 2), 0.0],
       [datetime.date(2024, 1, 2), 1.0],
       ...,
       [datetime.date(2024, 1, 10), 21.0],
       [datetime.date(2024, 1, 10), 22.0],
       [datetime.date(2024, 1, 10), 23.0]], dtype=object)

But, this is not a good use of numpy IMO (better use a structured array or pandas DataFrame in this case):
out = np.empty(len(a)*len(b), dtype=[('date', a.dtype), ('hour', b.dtype)])
out['date'] = np.repeat(a, len(b))
out['hour'] = np.tile(b, len(a))

array([('2024-01-01',  0.), ('2024-01-01',  1.), ('2024-01-01',  2.),
       ('2024-01-01',  3.), ('2024-01-01',  4.), ('2024-01-01',  5.),
       ('2024-01-01',  6.), ('2024-01-01',  7.), ('2024-01-01',  8.),
       ...,
       ('2024-01-10', 18.), ('2024-01-10', 19.), ('2024-01-10', 20.),
       ('2024-01-10', 21.), ('2024-01-10', 22.), ('2024-01-10', 23.)],
      dtype=[('date', '<M8[D]'), ('hour', '<f8')])

Or:
import pandas as pd

out = pd.DataFrame({'date': a}).merge(pd.DataFrame({'hour': b}), how='cross')

          date  hour
0   2024-01-01   0.0
1   2024-01-01   1.0
2   2024-01-01   2.0
3   2024-01-01   3.0
4   2024-01-01   4.0
..         ...   ...
235 2024-01-10  19.0
236 2024-01-10  20.0
237 2024-01-10  21.0
238 2024-01-10  22.0
239 2024-01-10  23.0

[240 rows x 2 columns]


Thanks for that Mozway. It works as a solution but what I was hoping to achieve was two columns [0] = date ( - which would repeat over 24 rows) and [1] hour 0 to 23 for that date.

@Seamus please edit your question to add the explicit expected output (you can decrease to 2 days and 3 hours to keep the example short)

Yeah, I'm agreeing with you. I'm looking for the fastest way to build a year's data based on three variables (0-7, 1-30, 0-30) which would yield >65m rows ultimately :-(

I added alternative approaches using structured arrays and pandas, which should be preferred to an object array

Thanks again Mozway. I've research to do !!! but your help has been significant. Much appreciated.

I believe that what you are trying to achieve is the cartesian product of the two arrays.
In order to obtain that, you can use itertools.product from the standard library:
permutations = list(itertools.product(a, b))

The result is:
[
(numpy.datetime64('2024-01-01'), 0),
(numpy.datetime64('2024-01-01'), 1),
(numpy.datetime64('2024-01-01'), 2),
...
]


IT was @robertoschiavone. Thanks for that. I couldn't think of the mathematical term I was looking for.

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder as le
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Define the date range and hours
# Create a date range from 1990-01-01 to 1990-01-10
dates = np.arange(np.datetime64('1990-01-01'), np.datetime64('1990-01-11'))  
# Create an array of hours from 0 to 23
hours = np.linspace(0, 23, 24).astype(int)  

# Create label encoders for dates and hours
le_hours = le()
le_dates = le()

# Encode dates and hours
date_encoded = le_dates.fit_transform(dates.astype(str)) 
hour_encoded = le_hours.fit_transform(hours)  

# Create all combinations of dates and hours
 # Repeat each date for all hours
date_repeated = np.repeat(date_encoded, len(hours))
# Tile the hour array for all dates 
hour_tiled = np.tile(hour_encoded, len(dates))  

# Decode the encoded dates and hours back to original format
date_decoded = le_dates.inverse_transform(date_repeated)  
hour_decoded = le_hours.inverse_transform(hour_tiled)  

# Combine dates and hours into a single array
data = np.column_stack([date_decoded, hour_decoded])  
# Create a pandas DataFrame from the array
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date', 'Hour']) 
print(df)
'''
           Date Hour
0    1990-01-01    0
1    1990-01-01    1
2    1990-01-01    2
3    1990-01-01    3
4    1990-01-01    4
..          ...  ...
235  1990-01-10   19
236  1990-01-10   20
237  1990-01-10   21
238  1990-01-10   22
239  1990-01-10   23
'''


Thanks @Soudipta, that's quite an elegant solution. However, I'd implemented the one mozway suggested as soon as it came in. I have a sneaky suspicion that yours might be 'more correct' albeit longer in code.
